# Using Eclipse with a Low-Resolution Monitor

Tags: eclipse

Many affordable laptops these days have resolution of 800 lines or less.  I know you can plug in an external monitor, but sometimes that's not an option (eg travel to a client site).  I'm used to having two huge monitors for development and feel completely paralyzed when trying to use a laptop to do coding.

So, my main questions is for Eclipse users on these low resolution machines.  What are some coping strategies that you use to be an efficient coder in Eclipse?  For example, I noticed that double clicking a tab opens it full screen (which has pros and cons).  And I can press ctrl-shift-t to pop-up a dialog to find a class (so I don't have to hunt for it in all my packages).  I'm sure people with years of Eclipse coding on a laptop have some tricks they found helpful.  Please share them here for everyone if you do.

Thanks

Comment: If you got a good answer, please choose it as the best answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a machine with 1366x768 resolution. My way of coding with eclipse is collapsing all unused methods. I unfortunately don't remember where in the settings it is, but you can choose whether you want to have all methods collapsed if you load a file. This comes pretty handy if you have large code projects.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, I use eclipse on an Acer Netbook with a 10.1 inch screen. :) I have closed all the floating and docked windows around the IDE except the editor itself (obviously) and the Project Explorer. And also the toolbars. Get used to all the shortcuts. Works like a charm and saves you many mouse-strokes too.

As for the editor, collapse all the methods and classes. (Eclipse has a + or - button next to the signatures). And use code-folding (see the eclipse docs).

And thanks for the double-click-to-open-in-full-screen thing. I didn't know it.